# SQL: difference between where in main body vs join clause

Tags: sql, mysql-5.6

I'm wondering why does the following queries give me a slightly different dataset:

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(e.id)
FROM event_type t
LEFT JOIN event e ON t.id = e.type_id AND e.start BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY t.name;

SELECT t.name, COUNT(e.id)
FROM event_type t
LEFT JOIN event e ON t.id = e.type_id
WHERE e.start BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY t.name;
```

So I just moved `BETWEEN` clause to the main body, logically, it does not matter where to apply it, but the result says it matters. Any suggestions? Thanks!

UPD: tried on MySQL 5.6

```
create table event_type
(
    id       int auto_increment primary key,
    name     varchar(100) not null,
    constraint UNIQ_93151B825E237E06 unique (name)
) collate = utf8_unicode_ci;


create table event
(
    id                         int auto_increment primary key,
    type_id                    int                  null,
    start                      datetime             not null,
    ...

    constraint FK_3BAE0AA7C54C8C93
        foreign key (type_id) references event_type (id)
) collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create index IDX_3BAE0AA7C54C8C93
    on event (type_id);
```

Comment: Is this mysql or postgresql? Please provide sample data, where there is a difference.

Comment: Those two queries should return identical results. If not, this sounds like a bug. In that case, it's even more important which DBMS you are using (and it's exact version).

Comment: For ``Inner join``, result should be the same but for ``left`` or ``right`` join there is some differences. could you please provide sample data?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad I'm sorry, actually it is LEFT join

Comment: If you include conditions in `WHERE` for a `LEFT JOIN` it essentially gets mutated to an `INNER JOIN` as the `WHERE` can only be evaluated on the joined results. Putting the condition within the `JOIN` means that only those values get joined. Hence the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's hard to answer this question without some images! but I try.

Let's assume this is the `event_type` table

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First |
| 2 | Second |

`Events` table:

| Id | TypeId | Start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-10-01 |
| 6 | 1 | 2022-10-10 |

So for this query:

```sql
SELECT t.name, COUNT(e.id)
FROM event_type t
LEFT JOIN event e ON t.id = e.type_id AND e.start BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-05'
GROUP BY t.name;
```

The result will be:

| Name | Count(e.id) |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1 |
| Second | 0 |

But why? becuase sql engine when try to get result on left join, it will check both of `id` and `start`, actually the result of prevois query is like this:

| Id | Name | Id | TypeId | Start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | First | 5 | 1 | 2022-10-01 |
| 2 | Second | null | null | null |

That's it! When you try to use `Between` in `where` clause, in fact you are filtering the null values so sql would ingore them and the final result would be different.

I hope it's clear enough!

Comment: it's clear enough indeed! thank you!